# how to add new CMS Block on login page magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to insert new block on login page in magento 2. Can anyone help me how can I add new block on login page?

Comment: what mean by block?CMS  Block or Block?

Comment: It is CMS Block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add new block by creating a new module. for example :

Make a new directory in `app/code/`

In this create another folders `Foo/Bar`

For creating module, create module.xml in `Foo/Bar/etc/module.xml`.

*And paste this code*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Foo_Bar" setup_version="2.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Run this `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` in your CLI for create module.

Create `Foo/Bar/Block/Baz.php`

and paste this code

```
 <?php 
   namespace Foo\Bar\Block; 
 class Baz
    extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
    public function getTitle()
 {
    return "New Block";
  }
}
```

create `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml`

and paste this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Foo\Bar\Block\Baz" template="Foo_Bar::default/baz.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

create `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/templates/default/baz.phtml`

and paste this code

```
<?php
?>
  <h1tag><?php echo $block->getTitle(); ?></h1tag>
```

Remove **cache** and check your block by reloading login page.

Answer (score 8):

In Admin Panel :
go to **content > widgets > Add Widget >** *then*

[image]

click on the continue button

[image]

and select the block you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

Add it via widget, Add a new widget of CMS static block type and than in widget options select your specific page.

Comment: What you mean by physically? via XML or PHP code. What code you have in your block and what you want to achieve.

Comment: physically means programmatically. via PHP code